# Removing CN1Preferences ads from the Storage Codename One

Tags: codenameone

By taking this example: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Storage.html

How to remove the CN1Preferences 100bytes which is displayed everytime I restart my application, no matter how many times I remove it, it comes back after restarting, however in the Simulator I have no issue with that.

Also how to not display a specific item from the listEntries, how to do that? Because it's displaying my serialized object from other purposes and I don't want my customers removing it by accident, so I wish I could not display a specific object from the listEntries storage in order to avoid my customers removing it.

Comment: I imagine it contains information to speed up loading the app after the first time that CN1 automatically adds. Why do you want to remove it? Is it causing some issue?

Comment: I want to remove it in order to present a clean container for my customers who will store their info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use storage for things we need through the Preferences API. The assumption of "clean" is incorrect. The OS might also add files anywhere.

If you want to show a file picker UI just ignore files that have a different extension than your extension and hide them. Hide the extension too to make this seamless.